# How to iterate a string character wise and store in an array index in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, string, loops

I want to store 15 string characters in an array index and the next 15 characters in the other index.

Array index 0 = "123456789012345"
Array index 1 = "678901234567890"

```
            var newData:String[] = [];
            let word = "";
            let Inctext = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
           
            for (let i = 0; i < Inctext.length; i++)
            {
               word +=  Inctext[i]
               console.log(word)
               newData[i] = word
               console.log(newData)

            }
```

Array index 0 = "123456789012345"
Array index 1 = "678901234567890"
and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const word = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
const chunkedWord = [];
for (let i = 0; i < (word.length / 15); i++) {
    const chunkStart = i * 15;
    const chunkEnd = chunkStart + 15;
    chunkedWord[i] = word.slice(chunkStart, chunkEnd);
}
console.log(chunkedWord)
```

The for loop iterates n times, whereas n is the length of word divided by 15. Hence, each iteration deals with a 15 character chunk of `word`. For each chunk we calculate its start and end. The start of a chunk is its position (starting from 0) in the chunk array multiplied by the chunk length (15). The end is the chunk start incremented by the chunk length (15).

Based on `chunkStart` and `chunkEnd`, we [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?retiredLocale=de) a 15 character chunk out of `word` and assign it to the corresponding index of `chunkedWord`. By doing `word.length / 15` in the for loop, we make sure that chunkedWord has the right amount of indices.